# Convert from comma to Column (sed)

Tags: sed, csv, columns

I have a *.csv file that has some text in the following format:

```
a, b, c 
d, e, f
g, h, i
```

And I would like to convert this into an *.xls file with three columns. Is it possible to do it with "sed"?

Edit: This is just an example. What I'm interested in is replacing a symbol with a column shift (if this is not impossible). Next, I want to manipulate a text that looks like this:

A single column

```
a[kg/m]
```

to two column format

```
a     [kg/m]
```

I'm not sure it is possible, though! But I know that "sed" can do a lot of tricks to replace and modify *.csv files

Comment: Do your fields have commas inside them? Like `foo, "foo, bar", 42`

Comment: It is a plain text with comma in between. The *.csv extension was experimental.

Comment: Why you don't open the `CSV` with excel and then save it as `XLS`?

Comment: Just did that. What I have now is a one-column format with text separated by comma in each row. 
a, b, c in one column
d, e, f  in the same column etc.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you running?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2010

Comment: normally when you open a csv with Excel 2010 the application asks you what the delimiter is. It didn't in your case?

Comment: Nope. I have this option if I use LibreCalc, though. But I have a couple of documents and it's always easy just to use a command and include multiple files rather than opening one by one. I need to separate the columns for importing tables in Latex.

Comment: excel imports csv's and interprets them properly

Comment: I will have to do more things with that doc, and it is therefore important that I can convert a symbol to a "column". 

After comma, I have some text in square brackets that I want to move to a column.

Comment: Please see my edit!

Comment: you did read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba ?

Comment: That looks like a one-by-one opening and saving etc. I would like to do it for multiple files at once. (btw, thank you for the link!)

Comment: And BTW, I have managed to separate the comma with excel. Thanks for that. It would be nice if I could do the same using a command.

Comment: Why is this question posted in `Unix & Linux`?

Comment: Isn't "sed" a command for Linux?

Comment: `sed` is a streaming editor. It can manipulate an input stream. So as an example to replace all `,` with `;` you could use:
`sed -i 's/,/;/g' your_file.csv`

Comment: That's very close to what I want! So instead of replacing "," with ";", is there any possibility to change it to a tab corresponding to a column separator, which can be then opened in excel as columns? (Again, I might be asking for flying horses here, so please correct me).

Comment: Simply replacing commas with tabs will not turn a .csv file into a proper .xls file. Use [Excel to convert the files](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-convert-delimited-text-files-into-excel-spreadsheets/)

Comment: I see. So I need to come up with another strategy. Thank you guys for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if understand correctly the scond part of your request:

> A single column `a[kg/m]` to two column format `a     [kg/m]`

But this will convert your csv into a tab separated file and with the extra column before [Kg/m]:

`sed -e 's/,/\t/g' -e 's:\(\[Kg/m\]\):\t\1:g' afile.csv > newfile.csv`

Example:

```
$ cat afile.csv
a[Kg/m],b[Kg/m],c
d[Kg/m],e[Kg/m],f
g[Kg/m],h[Kg/m],i

$ sed -e 's/,/\t/g' -e 's=\(\[Kg/m\]\)=\t\1=g' afile.csv > newfile.csv

$ cat newfile.csv
a       [Kg/m]  b       [Kg/m]  c
d       [Kg/m]  e       [Kg/m]  f
g       [Kg/m]  h       [Kg/m]  i
```

There are two scripts in this sed command:

- `-e 's/,/\t/g'` replaces `','` into `<tab>`
- `-e 's=\(\[Kg/m\]\)=\t\1=g'` replaces any `[Kg/m]` for `<tab>[Kg/m]`

Now, without replacing into tabs, you can add an extra column to your csv file with this:

```
$ sed -e 's=\(\[Kg/m\]\)=,\1=g' afile.csv > newfile.csv
$ cat newfile.csv
a,[Kg/m],b,[Kg/m],c
d,[Kg/m],e,[Kg/m],f
g,[Kg/m],h,[Kg/m],i
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!